# Automatically aborting OWIN request

Tags: asp.net, async-await, owin, nancy

If i have a OWIN-based ASP.NET web application (specifically, Nancy) running on IIS/Azure Websites, is there any way to *terminate* the HTTP request automatically, after a given timeout?

Basically, we are seeing requests running for minutes/hours... and whilst the root cause is yet to be unidentified, and most likely an async/await 'deadlock' issue, it would be good if we could automatically abort the upper level HTTP request after say, 30 seconds.

Is this possible, perhaps with a config setting or using CancellationTokens?